# Why my code is recording into the file only when I run it second time?

Tags: python

My goal is to calculate amount of words. When I run my code I am suppose to:

1. read in strings from the file
2. split every line in words
3. add these words into the dictionary
4. sort keys and add them to the list
5. write the string that consists of keys and appropriate values into the file

When I run code for the first time it does **not** write anything in the file, but I see the result on my screen. The file is empty. Only when I run code second time I see content is recorded into the file.

Why is that happening?

```
#read in the file
fileToRead = open('../folder/strings.txt')
fileToWrite = open('../folder/count.txt', 'w')

d = {}
#iterate over every line in the file
for line in fileToRead:
    listOfWords = line.split()
    #iterate over every word in the list
    for word in listOfWords:
        if word not in d:
            d[word] = 1
        else:
            d[word] = d.get(word) + 1
#sort the keys
listF = sorted(d)

#iterate over sorted keys and write them in the file with appropriate value
for word in listF:
    string = "{:<18}\t\t\t{}\n".format(word, d.get(word))
    print string
    fileToWrite.write(string)
```

Comment: Do you ever close the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimalistic version:

```
import collections

with open('strings.txt') as f:
    d = collections.Counter(s for line in f for s in line.split())

with open('count.txt', 'a') as f:
    for word in sorted(d.iterkeys()):
        string = "{:<18}\t\t\t{}\n".format(word, d[word])
        print string,
        f.write(string)
```

Comment: Ah, no, you're right. You're building a generator of words and passing it to the `Counter`. I mistook that to hand each word to an individual `Counter` (the way my code did it: `d = sum([Counter(line.split()) for line in f])`)

Comment: Both worked for me. Thank you. I still cannot get used to write these statements: "s for line in f for s in line.split()". But I still want to know why sum in the Adam's cases didn't work. It supposed to.   P.S. Both answers are great. Sorry I cannot chose two for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Couple changes, it think you meant 'a' (append to file) instead of 'w' overwrite file each time in open('count.txt', 'a'). Please also try to use with statement for reading and writing files, as it automatically closes the file descriptor after the read/write is done.

```
#read in the file
fileToRead = open('strings.txt')

d = {}
#iterate over every line in the file
for line in fileToRead:
    listOfWords = line.split()
    #iterate over every word in the list
    for word in listOfWords:
        if word not in d:
            d[word] = 1
        else:
            d[word] = d.get(word) + 1
#sort the keys
listF = sorted(d)

#iterate over sorted keys and write them in the file with appropriate value
with open('count.txt', 'a') as fileToWrite:
    for word in listF:
        string = "{:<18}\t\t\t{}\n".format(word, d.get(word))
        print string,
        fileToWrite.write(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `file.write(some_data)`, it writes the data into a buffer but *not* into the file. It only saves the file to disk when you do `file.close()`.

```
f = open('some_temp_file.txt', 'w')

f.write("booga boo!")
# nothing written yet to disk

f.close()
# flushes the buffer and writes to disk
```

The better way to do this would be to store the path in the variable, rather than the file object. Then you can open the file (and close it again) on demand.

```
read_path = '../folder/strings.txt'
write_path = '../folder/count.txt'
```

This also allows you to use the `with` keyword, which handles file opening and closing much more elegantly.

```
read_path = '../folder/strings.txt'
write_path = '../folder/count.txt'

d = dict()

with open(read_path) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        for word in line.split()
            d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1
            # remember dict.get's default value! Saves a conditional

# since we've left the block, `inf` is closed by here

sorted_words = sorted(d)

with open(write_path, 'w') as outf:
    for word in sorted_words:
        s = "{:<18}\t\t\t{}\n".format(word, d.get(word))
        # don't shadow the stdlib `string` module
        # also: why are you using both fixed width AND tab-delimiters in the same line?
        print(s)  # not sure why you're doing this, but okay...
        outf.write(s)
# since we leave the block, the file closes automagically.
```

That said, there's a couple things you could do to make this a little better *in general*. First off: counting how many of something are in a container is a job for a `collections.Counter`.

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: Counter('abc')
Out[2]: Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})
```

and `Counter`s can be added together with the expected behavior

```
In [3]: Counter('abc') + Counter('cde')
Out[3]: Counter({'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1})
```

and also sorted the same way you'd sort a dictionary with keys

```
In [4]: sorted((Counter('abc') + Counter('cde')).items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])
Out[4]: [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('e', 1)]
```

Put those all together and you could do something like:

```
from collections import Counter

read_path = '../folder/strings.txt'
write_path = '../folder/count.txt'

with open(read_path) as inf:
    results = sum([Counter(line.split()) for line in inf])

with open(write_path, 'w') as outf:
    for word, count in sorted(results.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0]):
        s = "{:<18}\t\t\t{}\n".format(word, count)
        outf.write(s)
```

Comment: Thank you. But this line: results = sum([Counter(line.split()) for line in inf]) produces an error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'.   When I delete sum() and print it produces result of some number of counters. Sum supposed to work but it doesn't.       Thanks for the explanation of counters. I didn't know I could sum them.

Comment: The expression `[Counter(line.split()) for line in inf]` creates a list of `Counter` objects that cannot be `sum`-med with the default initial zero value. It's necessary to provide an explicit initial value so the working version is: `sum([Counter(line.split()) for line in inf], Counter())`.

Comment: Hmm I'm pretty sure I tested it, but don't have time to do so now. I suppose you could also do `functools.reduce(operator.add, [Counter(line.split()) for ... ])`